# Is the language $L = \{a^ib^jc^kd^l : i,j,k,l \geq 0 \text{ and } i + k = j + l\}$ context free language?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Is the language $L = \{a^ib^jc^kd^l : i,j,k,l \geq 0 \text{ and } i + k = j + l\}$ context free language?
My initial thought was to prove that it is not a CFL by using Pumping Lemma for CFG with the string $s = a^pb^pc^pd^p$. Since $|s| = 4p > p$, and $s \in L$, so I can divide it into $s = uvxyz$, where $|vy| \geq 1, |vxy| \leq p$. Then I check for all the possibilities of $|vxy|$ in $s$:

- $vxy = a^e$
- $vxy = a^eb^f$
- $vxy = b^ec^f$

The other two cases: $c^ed^f, d^e$ would be the same as the first two cases because the symmetric property. By pumping up $s$, I can see that $s_i \not\in L$. 
On the other hand, I've just learned pumping lemma for CFG, I couldn't convince myself this language is not context free. I wonder if anyone could give me a hint to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought that the language might be context-free?  If you cannot prove that it is not for a while, the next thing to do naturally is to try to prove that it is context-free.

Comment: A language is context-free if and only if there is a push-down automaton accepting it. The criterion for acceptance is equivalent to i - j + k - l = 0. Can a push-down automaton verify that this sum is equal to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Suppose wlog that $i \geq l$. Then
$$ a^i b^j c^k d^l = a^{l+(i-l)} b^{(i-l)+k} c^k d^l. $$

Comment: Thank you. I wonder what is `wlog`? Are you implying it is context free ^_^?

Comment: wlog = Without loss of generality.

Comment: Is it CFL? since I already found the case that no matter how I pump (up or down), it's still in $L$.

Comment: This might be my personal taste, but I do not like the use of “wlog” (or “without loss of generality” for that matter) here.

Comment: @Chan: You should think about the hint.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: I thought about it from yesterday until today. Still didn't see anything :(, could you give an extra hint? Thank you.

Comment: @Chan: Hint: Is $x^ny^n$ context-free?

Comment: So $L$ is context-free ?

Comment: @user220688 What do you think?

Comment: I can construct automat with stack which recognizes this language

Comment: Then you get: $S\to aSd | AB ~~ A \to aAb | \epsilon ~~ B \to bBc | \epsilon$ but you miss a case here!

Answer (score 0):

To me, the simplest approach to this question seems to be in terms of constructing a pushdown automaton to recognize the language.  Note that the condition is equivalent to $i-j+k-l = 0$, so in effect we want to count each $a,c$ as positive and $b,d$ as negative, and see if in the end they balance.  So, at any point, the operation of the pushdown automaton is:

- If you see $a$: push it on the stack.
- If you see $b$: if $a$ is the top of the stack, pop it.  Otherwise, push $b$ on the stack.
- If you see $c$: if $b$ is the top of the stack, pop it.  Otherwise, push $c$ on the stack.
- If you see $d$: if $a$ or $c$ is the top of the stack, pop it.  Otherwise, reject the string.  (Or, push $d$ on the stack if an early reject is not an option in your formulation.)

At the end, if you have an empty stack, then the string is valid; otherwise, the string is invalid.  From here, you should just be able to throw in a few states to make sure that $a,b,c,d$ occur in the correct order.

Since there is a pushdown automaton which recognizes the given language, that language is context-free.

Comment: Need also keep track if you are in the $a$, $b$, $c$ or $d$ stretch (use states).