# Construct Context-Free Grammar for $\{a^ib^jc^kd^l : i,j,k,l\geq1\:\land\: i+j=k+l\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

One of the tasks on my exam was to construct a context-free grammar for the language:

$$L = \{a^ib^jc^kd^l : i,j,k,l\geq1\:\land\: i+j=k+l\}$$

I have no clue how to construct such a grammar, could someone help me?

Comment: Hint: If you know how to construct a context-free grammar for the intersection of a context-free and a regular language (where you have a grammar for the first and a finite state machine for the second), then you could express $L$ as the intersection of $\{ vw \mid v \in (a|b)^*, w \in (c|d)^*, |v| = |w| \}$ and the regular language for the expression $aa^* bb^* cc^* dd^*$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help me much, I've never heard of such a thing as context-free grammar of intersection. I just don't understand how I'm supposed to meet the condition that the total number of a and b is equal to the total number of c and d because that's what it comes down to.

Comment: Well, OK then, would you be able to find a grammar for $\{ vw \mid v \in (a|b)^*, w \in (c|d)^*, |v| = |w| \}$?  That exercise would at least be similar enough to $L$ to hopefully give you some idea.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57621/305862)

Comment: @DanielSchepler But for this vw language I have the same problem, how do I make sure that |v| = |w|?

Comment: For that other language, the idea is: $L' \rightarrow a L' c ~|~ a L' d ~|~ b L' c ~|~ b L' d ~|~ \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that I can use recursion, maybe I will come up with something.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I've been thinking about this since yesterday but still have no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about how you might check the condition $i+j = k+l$, one way that comes to mind would be: repeatedly peel off an $a$ or a $b$ from the start, and at the same time peel off a $c$ or a $d$ from the end.  If at any time you reach a string with only $a$ and $b$, then at the start you had $i+j > k+l$ so the string does not match the condition.  Similarly, if you reach a string with only $c$ and $d$, then at the start you had $i+j < k+l$.  But if you reach an empty string, then the total number of $a$ and $b$ matched the total number of $c$ and $d$.

However, on top of this, you have the restriction that once you've peeled off a $b$ from the start, you can never see $a$ at the start again; and similarly, once you've peeled off a $c$ from the end, you can never see $d$ at the end again.  So, to reflect this, you will need to keep track of whether you've seen a $b$ peeled off from the left, and whether you've seen a $c$ peeled off from the right.

Keeping this in mind (as well as the fact that at the start, you must peel off an $a$ and a $d$ since $i, l \ge 1$), a grammar for the language could look something like:

\begin{align*}
S \rightarrow & ~ a ~ ABCD ~ d \\
ABCD \rightarrow & ~ a ~ ABCD ~ d \\
| & ~ a ~ ABC ~ c \\
| & ~ b ~ BCD ~ d \\
| & ~ b ~ BC ~ c \\
ABC \rightarrow & ~ a ~ ABC ~ c \\
| & ~ b ~ BC ~ c \\
BCD \rightarrow & ~ b ~ BCD ~ d \\
| & ~ b ~ BC ~ c \\
BC \rightarrow & ~ b ~ BC ~ c \\
| & ~ \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Here the grammar incorporates the requirement $j, k \ge 1$ in the fact that by the time you reach the "leaf" production $BC \rightarrow \varepsilon$, you must have peeled off $b$ on the left at least once, and also must have peeled off $c$ on the right at least once.

Comment: Ok I understand how this grammar works only I don't understand how this grammar is context-free since there is more than one nonterminal on the left side of production

Comment: Here each of $ABCD$, $ABC$, $BCD$, $BC$ represents a single nonterminal symbol.  (Using multiple-lettered names for convenience, in a way similar to the way a grammar for arithmetic expressions might have non-terminal symbols $Expr$, $Summand$, $Factor$, etc.)

Comment: So if you wanted to use single letters (say $E,F,G,H$) instead, the rules would look like $S \rightarrow a E d$, $E \rightarrow aEd | aFc | bGd | bHc$, etc.

Comment: I finally understand, well this grammar is not so complicated the problem is just to figure it out.